# Update MySQL Column from a list

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to change the Transaction date from this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orderslip_transaction` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- Indexes for table `orderslip_transaction`
--
ALTER TABLE `orderslip_transaction`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `transaction_number` (`transaction_number`),
  ADD KEY `orderslip_transaction_user_id_dd45478c_fk_auth_user_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `store_id-fk-store` (`store_id`);
```

And some data:

```
INSERT INTO `orderslip_transaction` (`id`, `transaction_number`, `transaction_date`, `transaction_is_active`, `store_id`, `created_on`, `updated_on`, `user_id`) VALUES
(243, '1540 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-01 03:23:00', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 11:13:14.026696', '2022-12-10 11:13:14.026696', 1), 
(244, '1541 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-01 04:00:29', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 11:11:26.442181', '2022-12-10 11:11:26.457804', 1), 
(247, '1545 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-01 07:19:08', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 11:09:10.739268', '2022-12-10 11:09:10.739268', 1), 
(248, '1546 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-01 10:14:45', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 11:19:31.026184', '2022-12-10 11:19:31.026184', 1), 
(262, '1577 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-01 08:36:15', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 12:09:06.744023', '2022-12-10 12:09:06.744023', 1), 
(271, '1583 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-01 13:30:31', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 12:02:36.909668', '2022-12-10 12:02:36.925290', 1);
```

(This is from the MySQL Export)

What I want to do is to change the transaction date from a csv list with this example data set:

```
('1545 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-10 07:19:08', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 11:09:10.739268', '2022-12-10 11:09:10.739268', 1), 
('1546 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-12 10:14:45', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 11:19:31.026184', '2022-12-10 11:19:31.026184', 1), 
('1577 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-23 08:36:15', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 12:09:34.693302', '2022-12-10 12:09:34.693302', 1),
('1583 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-24 13:30:31', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 12:02:36.909668', '2022-12-10 12:02:36.925296', 1);
```

I tried using

```
INSERT INTO orderslip_transaction (transaction_number, transaction_date, transaction_is_active, store_id, created_on, updated_on, user_id) VALUES
('1545 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-10 07:19:08', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 11:09:10.739268', '2022-12-10 11:09:10.739268', 1), 
('1546 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-12 10:14:45', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 11:19:31.026184', '2022-12-10 11:19:31.026184', 1), 
('1577 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-23 08:36:15', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 12:09:34.693302', '2022-12-10 12:09:34.693302', 1),
('1583 | ALLCPB', '2022-12-24 13:30:31', 1, 1, '2022-12-10 12:02:36.909668', '2022-12-10 12:02:36.925296', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE orderslip_transaction.transaction_date = VALUES(transaction_date);
```

I purposefully omitted the `id` column in the `INSERT...` statement since I only would like to check for the `transaction_number`. Running the query does not result in an error, but the result when querying `SELECT * FROM orderslip_transaction WHERE transaction_number = "1583 | ALLCPB";` stil gives me `2022-12-01 13:30:31.000000` as its transaction_date. I don't need to change the other columns, just the transaction_date column.

Further reading from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/, I saw that `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ()` only works well when there is only 1 primary key, and that using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE might not produce the desired results when there are more than 1 unique keys (in this case, `id` and `transaction_number` are both unique, with `id` being an auto-increment primary key)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I'm running XAMPP v3.3.0, MySQL v5+, btw.

Comment: As an additional info on this, the December 1 dates for all the records were caused by my bone-headed update that set ALL the dates to December 1, 2022. There are 40,000+ records on the db, and the csv file which contains the correct dates for the transactions will be the source of the update. As mentioned in the question, I on need to update the `transaction_date`. All other columns should not be changed.

Lesson learned. ALWAYS have a backup, DOUBLE-CHECK the query, AND use TRANSACTIONS (for rollback capability in case something like this happens again, which should not!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Running the query does not result in an error

This is extremely strange. You **must** receive an error similar to "Column `id` does not have default value". Maybe you hide it by some way? The fact that the data is not updated also confirms that the query fails.

While fixing this issue you query runs successfully. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1_s0zefw).

But I recommend you not to set default value but to make `id` autoincremented.

---

> Further reading from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/, I saw that ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE () only works well when there is only 1 primary key, and that using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE might not produce the desired results when there are more than 1 unique keys (in this case, id and transaction_number are both unique, with id being an auto-increment primary key)

I think that this is not correct. ODKU fires when ANY unique index violation is detected. The article by the link tries to tell that if some unique key violation is found and ODKU is fired then some other unique key violation may occur which will result in the whole query fail (common double fault) - but the same can be produced on one unique key easily.. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-N4YMQVg).

Comment: Hi @Akina, thanks for pointing these out. As for the error, as mentioned, I do not receive errors, phpmyadmin just tells me 0 rows were affected, which does mean that the query fails, since a successful firing of the query should give me 2 rows updated (per row) when ODKU is successful. Another thing is that `id` column is `auto-increment` and this is a column accessed by other tables' foreign key, so I shouldn't be changing them, that is why I did not use `REPLACE INTO...` for the update since doing so will generate a new id for the same Transaction Number. Thoughts?

Comment: @AllanCaps *Another thing is that id column is auto-increment* You provide the table structure. And I do not see AI in it...

Comment: *doing so will generate a new id for the same Transaction Number* INSERT will generate new value anycase. And when unique index violation detected and ODKU fired then this newly generated value is lost/skipped, and a gap in AI values occures.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Akina! I tinkered with the fiddle, and it did what it was supposed to do. This is why I am accepting your answer. Though I did not proceed with this, as I just based the edits from another table where there were indicators of the correct Transaction Dates, and mapped those out to change all Transaction dates for a specific date. But thank you nonetheless. I learned a lot from this ODKU reply! :)